# Picking input record fields with AWK

Tags: arrays, awk

Let's say we have a shell variable `$x` containing a space separated list of numbers from 1 to 30:

```sh
$ x=$(for i in {1..30}; do echo -n "$i "; done)
$ echo $x
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

We can print the first three input record fields with AWK like this:

```sh
$ echo $x | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3}'
1 2 3
```

How can we print all the fields starting from the Nth field with AWK? E.g.

```
4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

EDIT: I can use cut, sed etc. to do the same but in this case I'd like to know how to do this with AWK.

Comment: The output is newline separated. It should be separated by space.

Comment: Check my updated command by refreshing page

Comment: In the comments of a deleted answer you wrote: _In the actual case there's various number of spaces between fields_; do you want to preserve those varying amounts of space?

Comment: It should be: `awk '{for (i=3; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%s", $i (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file `

Comment: @james-brown, I prefer not to preserve them but it's ok if it makes the command shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '{for (i=3; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%s", $i (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file
```

or pass start position as argument:

```sh
awk -v n=3 '{for (i=n; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%s", $i (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Version 4: Shortest is probably using `sub` to cut off the first three fields and their separators:

```
$ echo $x | awk 'sub(/^ *([^ ]+ +){3}/,"")'
```

Output:

```
4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
```

This will, however, preserve all space after `$4`:

```
$ echo "1 2 3  4   5" | awk 'sub(/^ *([^ ]+ +){3}/,"")'
4   5
```

so if you wanted the space squeezed, you'd need to, for example:

```
$ echo "1 2 3  4   5" | awk 'sub(/^ *([^ ]+ +){3}/,"") && $1=$1'
4 5
```

with the exception that if there are only 4 fields and the 4<sup>th</sup> field happens to be a 0:

```
$ echo "1 2 3 0" | awk 'sub(/^ *([^ ]+ +){3}/,"")&&$1=$1'
$ [no output]
```

in which case you'd need to:

```
$ echo "1 2 3 0" | awk 'sub(/^ *([^ ]+ +){3}/,"") && ($1=$1) || 1'
0
```

<s>Version 1: `cut` is better suited for the job:</s>

```
$ cut -d\  -f 4- <<<$x
```

Version 2: Using awk you could:

```
$ echo -n $x | awk -v RS=\  -v ORS=\  'NR>=4;END{printf "\n"}'
```

Version 3: If you want to preserve those varying amounts of space, using GNU awk you could use `split`'s fourth parameter `seps`:

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4  5   6    7" | 
gawk '{
    n=split($0,a,FS,seps)                     # actual separators goes to seps
    for(i=4;i<=n;i++)                         # loop from 4th
        printf "%s%s",a[i],(i==n?RS:seps[i])  # get fields from arrays
}'
```

Comment: In the actual case there's various number of spaces between fields. I'll add this note in the question.

Comment: That is a game changer.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I go with @anubhava's answer because it's more compact.

Comment: If you want compact, `cut`is the way. If you `echo $x | cut` (no quotes around `$x`) the extra space gets squeezed off. This will of course only work if the separators are space. Nvm, you wanted awk for wak's sake.

Answer (score 2):

Adding one more approach to add all value into a variable and once all fields values are done with reading just print the value of variable. Change the value of `n=` as per from which field onwards you want to get the data.

```
echo "$x" |
awk -v n=3 '{val="";for(i=n; i<=NF; i++){val=(val?val OFS:"")$i};print val}'
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk, you can use the [join function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Join-Function) which has been a built-in `include` since gawk 4.1:

```
x=$(seq 30 | tr '\n' ' ')

echo "$x" | gawk '@include "join"   
                {split($0, arr)
                print join(arr, 4, length(arr), "|")}
                '
4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30
```

(Shown here with a `'|'` instead of a `' '` for clarity...)

Alternative way of including `join`:

```
echo "$x" | gawk -i join '{split($0, arr); print join(arr, 4, length(arr), "|")}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu awk and gensub:

```
echo $x | awk '{ print gensub(/^([[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]){3}(.*$)/,"\\2",$0)}'
```

Using gensub, split the string into two sections based on regular expressions and print the second section only.